# A notational confusion on gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, manifolds

Given a parametrized function $f_{w}: \Bbb R ^{m} \to \Bbb R ^{k}, w \in \Bbb R^d$, I see in a book the following notation $\bigtriangledown ^ {w} f_{w}(.)$ denote its gradient w.r.t. $w$. What is the meaning of it ? Also, in other place, the notation $\bigtriangledown ^ {w} g(.)$ is used where $g$ is a scalar-valued function. Confused with the meaning of it.

Answer (score 0):

So you have in fact a function
$$F:\quad{\mathbb R}^d\times{\mathbb R}^m \to{\mathbb R}^k, \qquad (w,x)\mapsto f_w(x)\ .$$
I'd think that $\nabla^w f_w(x_0)$ refers to changes of $F$ when $w$ undergoes an infinitesimal change, and $x_0$ stays fixed, in other words, that you take the gradient just with respect to the $w$-variables. Unpacking it all it looks like so: The function $F$ appears as
$$F(w,x)=f_w(x)=\bigl(f_1(w_1,\ldots ,w_d\,;x_1,\ldots, x_m),\ldots,f_k(w_1,\ldots ,w_d\,;x_1,\ldots, x_m)\bigr)\ .$$
Its gradient with respect to $w$ has $d$ components, each of these itself a vector with $k$ components. The $j$'th component of this gradient is given by
$$\bigl(\nabla^w f_w\bigr)_j=\left({\partial f_1\over\partial w_j},{\partial f_2\over\partial w_j},\ldots,{\partial f_k\over\partial w_j}\right)\qquad(1\leq j\leq d)\ .$$
A coordinate free way of writing this would be
$$F(w+W,x)-F(w,x)=\nabla^w F(w,x)\cdot W+\ o(|W|)\qquad(W\to0)\ .$$
Here $W$ is a variable increment vector attached at the point $w$.

Comment: thanks. another question if $\phi(x) = ||f_{w}(x)||^2$ where $x \in \Bbb R^{m}$ what is grad($\phi$).

Comment: What is $W$ ? is it a vector or a scalar.